# Using TransferHandler to drag and drop from one JFrame into another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jframe

I set a personal TransferHandler to my component:

```
myComponent.setTransferHandler(new PersonalTransferHandler());

class PersonalTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
   public boolean canImport(JComponent comp, DataFlavor[] flavour) {
    ... 
   }
   protected boolean hasFlavor(DataFlavor[] flavors) {
    ... 
   }
   public boolean importData(JComponent comp, Transferable t) {
    ...
   }
```

Also I have a **JTable** with draggable elements (using another TransferHandler). I would like to copy elements from the **JTable** into **myComponent**. It works fine if the **JTable** is in the same JFrame that **myComponent** but if it is in a different JFrame I can drag the elements but I cannot drop into the compoment (the PersonalTransferHandler methods are not ever invoked).

Comment: I never tried that but this issue is about System Clipboard, this is outside basic DnD

Comment: There is a solution but is not very clean. When you drag an element from JFrame1, setVisible(JFrame2) and then it works.

Comment: I'd to suggest post the SSCCE here, but you have to wait for answer, [sure maybe no one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745087/making-a-jeditorpane-with-html-put-correctly-formatted-text-in-clipboard)

Comment: See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I know, but it is not my code.

Comment: @StanislavL I don't use DropTarget.

Comment: Are the frames in the same jvm? If so, it is much simpler.  What are you trying to transfer? Objects, components etc?