# How to keep font unchanged when copied to a JEditorPane in java?

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I have a `JEditorPane` where I'll copy some text from other application e.g. Adobe Pagemaker, Corel Draw etc. I want to keep my fonts unchanged. How can I do it ?

Comment: You should look into `DataFlavors` and ways to implement RTF/HTML data transfer from `Clipboard` into your `JEditorPane`. [Similar problem discussed on Java Forums](http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/14610-clipboard-jtextpane.html).

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7745087/230513).

Answer (score 2):

> I want a `JEditorPane` with different font.

The examples in [*How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) may guide you in this. In particular, [`TextComponentDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html#eg) illustrates changing font characteristics both programmatically and interactively. See `initDocument()` for details.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set it in `StyleContext`, a default font and then set the `StyleContext` object for your JEditorPane

Read [about StyleContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyleContext.html)

Comment: I do not want it to be set a default font. I want a JEditorPane with different font.